# Alguém pode me explicar esse erro? TypeError: teste2() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

Tags: python

Estou tentando pegar os valores da função teste1(), que são duas matrizes, e passar para a função teste 2 e posteriormente imprimir, mas fica dando esse erro. Alguém pode explicar?

```
def teste1():
    v = [0,1,2,3,4]
    t = [5,6,7,8,9]
    
    return v, t
    
def teste2(v,t):
    
    print(v,t)
    

teste2(teste1())
```

Comment: Faça `teste2(*teste1())` o python implicitamente empacota o resultado de funções que retornam múltiplos valores em uma tupla.Veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/OsGFEC

Answer (score -3):

Acho que seu erro é simples de resolver, a sua função teste2 pede dois argumentos como você definiu, e você está colocando o retorno da função teste um em apenas um dos argumentos,
tipo,

```
teste2(teste1, #aqui tu esqueceu o segundo# )
```

acho que o melhor é tu deixar a função do teste 2 somente com um argumento para ser inserido, já que o seu teste1 retorna os dois valores, ou separa os valores do teste1 um em variáveis e ai sim inserir no teste2.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não cumprimente, não agradeça e não use bordões. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)